# android list inside layout

Tags: android, listview, layout

i am working on an Android app that needs showing a list[table], inside the layout[view]

I come from iPhone dev objC land, and i have an app that shows a table[list] inside the view[layout]

[image: list/table]

So how to show a list inside my layout, and place it to specified location [center],

ps. I havent found a list in the graphical layout editor of the xml, where is the list[table]?
2. I have done some tests with list views, but is a view, that replace the xml view, i want it inside my xml,,

thanks a lot!

Comment: what u want to exactly us to do ? design layout for u ????

Comment: @Richa, no that is not my aim, i want to know if is possible to put a list inside a layout[with other elements], and not have the list occupy the hole screen

Comment: @mako ya its very much possible to put a list inside a layout just make the list's height as wrap content and the parent layout in which the list is should have scrolling disabled.

Comment: @MaKo:its definately possible the only thing is that u need to give fix height to listview o/w it wont display views below list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, of course, you can do that

1) you need to have `listholder.xml` here, you can scratch anything in you layout view, either imageview, textview..etc. just don't forget to add ListView inside it. for example:

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/head_logo_bg">
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/background_label">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/city_txt" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Sydney"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="17sp"/>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="40sp">

    <ListView 
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:scrollingCache="false"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

2) For custom your own list item, you have to create `listitem.xml` i.e.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/listitemone"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10sp">

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical">
            <ImageView android:id="@+id/user_image"
                android:layout_width="80px" android:layout_height="80px"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="5px"
                android:src="@drawable/icon"
                />
    </LinearLayout>
    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/date_label"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/date"
                android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/date_value"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/date_label"
                android:layout_marginRight="20sp"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:text="MM/dd/YYYY"
                android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
      </RelativeLayout>
</LinerLayout>
```

3) create customAdapter in your activity, it would look like this;

```
public class MyListActivity extends ListActivity {

private ArrayList<Yourdata> yourdata = new ArrayList<Youdata>();
        @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listholder);    
               // yourdata might be array, arraylist etc. 

               MyCustomAdapter listadapter = new MyCustomAdapter(this, R.layout.listitem, yourdata);

          setListAdapter(listadapter);
}

private class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Yourdata>{
                //this case, i use Yourdata as type
        private ArrayList<Yourdata> items;

        public PreviousAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                ArrayList<Yourdata> items) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
            this.items = items;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = convertView;
            if(v == null) {
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = vi.inflate(R.layout.listitem, null);
            }
            Yourdata yt = items.get(position);
            if(yt != null){
             // Don't forget to use v.findView...., otherwise, it might force close when run app.
                TextView dateStr = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.date_value);

                    dateStr.setText(yt.getDate());
            }   
            return v;
        }



      }


}
```

P.S. the above code might not exactly right... just give you an idea :)
Here is a source about custom list (you might have seen it) hope it useful

http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

Answer (score 1):

I have try these example it's very nice.

you can get the example from

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/507651/Customized-Android-ListView-with-Image-and-Text?msg=4567162#xx4567162xx