# Android Tabhost + Dynamic Listviews + Bottom bar

Tags: android, listview, android-tabhost

I'm trying to create a Layout like in the picture I drew with my amazing Paint skills and I have a few doubts about it.

[image]

This layout has a tabhost and **in each** tab there's a listView with dinamically added items. Also, there should be a bottom bar with two text views and one button. This bottom bar would be common to all tabs.

Problems I found and other doubts:

- I'm not figuring out how to dock the footer bar to the bottom. I built a separate xml for it and "included" it after the tabWidget. Result: it shows up in every tab but doesn't stick to the bottom.
- For the dynamical list views, I do need to extend ListActivity, right? (I'm trying to do all the program within a single activity, by the way- is this ok, with several listviews and all?)

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. TabHost study this tutorial http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html (it will create separately  activity)
2. For the Bottom Bar, if you wish it show the same in every tab. Scratch it in you main tabhost xml
3. For ListView, u just put   inside your xml(which belong to each Tab). In addition, u can use both simple list view or custom your own list view. This is some example of custom list view  [android list inside layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8814556/android-list-inside-layout/8814978#8814978)

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

I'm sorry but I didn't understand this sentence:"Scratch it in you main tabhost xml". What do you mean with "scratch it"? Thanks

Comment: by the way, i'm not sure, whether put it into your main tabhost xml or your separate xml. Technically, it can do both i think, it depend on your purpose. In addition there are several ways to put the bottom bar at the bottom. i.e. define your layout to Bottom